# Direct ffmpeg -> OpenGL send without intermediary buffer copy

Tags: c, ffmpeg

To get a decoded frame from ffmpeg, there's the function `avcodec_receive_frame`:

```
int avcodec_receive_frame   (   AVCodecContext *    avctx,
        AVFrame *   frame 
    )
```

Documentation: https://libav.org/documentation/doxygen/master/group__lavc__decoding.html#ga11e6542c4e66d3028668788a1a74217c

The problem with this function is that I need to pass a frame to it like this:

```
avcodec_receive_frame(&context, &frame)
```

such that it will write the context into an `AVFrame*` just so I can pass it to OpenGL by doing another copy. That is, I make an unnecessary copy. For large video frames this could take time.

There should be a function like this:

```
int avcodec_receive_frame   (   AVCodecContext *    avctx,
        int (write_function*)(uint8_t data*, AVFrameParameters * parameters)
    )
```

this way I can pass a function pointer of a function that will take care of writing the video frame directly to OpenGL, without making an unnecessary copy. By the way, `AVFrameParameters` is a type I invented. It would have the parameters of the frame like color scheme, dimensions and stride, etc so I can upload properly to OpenGL.

Is there a way to do something like this? If not, why not?

**PS**: something even better would be for OpenGL to pass its GPU pointer to be so I can pass it to OpenGL, but I think this is too extreme

Answer (score 0):

**First the easy part:**

[glMapBuffer](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glMapBuffer.xhtml)

> map all of a buffer object's data store into the client's address space

[glGetBufferPointerv](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glGetBufferPointerv.xhtml)

> return the pointer to a mapped buffer object's data store

**Now the tricky part:**

The function `avcodec_receive_frame` expects a `AVFrame` structure allocated via `av_frame_alloc`.

[av_frame_alloc](https://libav.org/documentation/doxygen/master/group__lavu__frame.html#gac700017c5270c79c1e1befdeeb008b2f)

> this only allocates the AVFrame itself, not the data buffers. Those must be allocated through other means, e.g. with av_frame_get_buffer() or manually.

That means, you can initialize the frame manually (set the fields that suits your needs).

But i have no clue how this interferes with the `avcodec_receive_frame` (in case of frame referencing and allocating buffers, ...).

Comment: Won't glMapBuffer copy the buffer from the GPU and then give it to me so I can write to it? This would take time. The idea was to not even copy from GPU to RAM but pass from ffmpeg to OpenGL inside the GPU, but I guess this is not possible. Anyways, about `avcodec_receive_frame`, it should have a function pointer that receives the data, so I don't have to copy to RAM so I can copy again

Comment: Maybe you then should consider using [vdpau](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VDPAU) on Linux/Unix and [DXVA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DirectX_Video_Acceleration) on windows. `ffmpeg/libav` do support `vdpau` (i don't know about dxva). I don't have more 'direct' to offer.